# Transforming variable to LOG Function

Tags: sas

I am having issues transforming the population variables to their natural logarithm.

```
Data health1;
set health;
LOG(employed__population_16_years_a);
Run;
```

I am getting results but the field only has a decimal in it and no numbers.

Comment: Your posted code is not valid syntax. You cannot just call a function like that. You need to write a complete assignment statement.  Please show the data type of the input variable  and some example values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to send the results of `log` function to a variable.

```
data health1;
    set health;
    log_employed_population_16_years = LOG(employed__population_16_years_a);
Run;
```

Comment: I am still only getting decimals as results:

Comment: I have tried to add the picture, but it adds a column to the end, and the only data in the cells below that new column are decimals or dots, but no data.

Comment: You'll need to post an example of data that does not work in either `datalines` format, or a downloadable .csv or .sas7bdat file.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Upload some data to an external website like Google drive, Dropbox, etc. that will recreate the issue you are having. No one here can tell you why your log function is returning missing values without seeing the data.